# How to write a loop for creating cropped raster for every id of a shapefile with a raster base?

Tags: r, loops, raster

I'm still new to R and don't know how to create a loop for my workprocess to make it more efficient.

I have a Digital Elevation Model (raster `Barrow_5m.tif`), a shapefile for lakes and buffer with 10 iDs in a row of the table each.
In the script below I created a new raster file for all values of the lake and the buffer shape file with the data from the DEM raster. This works fine.

```
setwd("...")

Barrow_5m <- raster("Barrow_5m.tif")

Barrow_DTLB <- st_read("Barrow_DTLB.shp")

Barrow_DTLB_Buffer <- st_read("Barrow_DTLB_BufferOUT.shp")

Barrow_lake <- crop(Barrow_5m, extent(Barrow_DTLB))

raster_lake <- rasterize(Barrow_DTLB, Barrow_lake, mask = TRUE)

Barrow_buffer <- crop(Barrow_2m, extent(Barrow_DTLB_Buffer))

raster_buffer <- rasterize(Barrow_DTLB_Buffer, Barrow_buffer, mask = TRUE)

writeRaster(raster_lake, "raster_lake.tif")

writeRaster(raster_buffer, "raster_buffer.tif")
```

But now I want to have a raster file for every id of the lake and the buffer shapefile seperately, so 2x10 files.
I thought it's best to write a loop for this, but my skills are not enough so far to do this. 
Also other questions didn't bring the solution so far. I tried to help me with [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131150/save-rasters-created-by-loop-operation-to-different-directory?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Alternatively I could use my end product tif from the script above and undo this in files for every ID.

I want to write the loop and not do it by hand for all the IDs of the shapefiles, because afterwards I am going to do the same with an even bigger shapefile of more values.

Comment: Is `raster_lake` a raster with the ids of each lake (same question for `raster_buffer`)?

Comment: yes, they have the ID 0 to 10, so 11 values each. And each lake ID belongs to the same Buffer ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution now, by extracting data by the ID.
It creates a largelist with 11 elements and all values of each id, which is sufficient for my further work. You can also directly creat the mean, max, min, etc values of each element (so each ID).

```
k <- Barrow_DTLB$ID #k= number of rows
LakesA <- extract(raster_lakeA, Barrow_DTLB[k, ])
LakesA_mean <- extract(raster_lakeA, Barrow_DTLB[k, ], fun=mean)
```

Maybe this solution is also helpful for a few, who already viewed the question.

Comment: Why don't you do `LakesA_mean <- extract(raster_lakeA, Barrow_DTLB, fun=mean)` (that is, do you *need* a loop?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
for (i in unique(raster_lake)){
  r <- raster_lake
  r[!(values(r) == i)] <- NA
  r <- trim(r) 
  writeRaster(r, paste0("raster_lake_", i, ".tif"))
}
```